# Strim a line in a text file (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, file, text

I currently have several hundred file path in lines in a txt file I need to strim e.g.

```
report2011510222820.html:   <td width="60%" bgcolor="#f4f4f4" class="tablebody" valign="top">C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\calc.exe</td>
```

How could I take out "`report2011510222820.html:    &lt;td width="60%" bgcolor="#f4f4f4" class="tablebody" valign="top"&gt;" and "&lt;/td&gt;`", so I am just left with:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\calc.exe
```

The current code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s[2048];
    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin))
    {
        char *pos = strpbrk(s, "|\r\n");
        if (pos != 0)
            fputs(pos+1, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s[2048];
    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin))
    {
        char *pos = strpbrk(s, "|\r\n");
        if (pos != 0)
            fputs(pos+1, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
`

Comment: That is the current code I have

Comment: @pavium Hi, I think someone has edited for me

Comment: Do you have to do it in `C`? homework?

Answer (score 0):

To get your posted code working for the given example, the following changes could be made.

Change the `strpbrk` call to check for the angle bracket instead of the vertical bar (not sure if that was just a typo in the OP code or not):

```
  char *pos = strpbrk(s, ">\r\n");
```

And then change the `if (pos != 0 )` statement to the following.  It truncates the end of the string at the next angle bracket.

```
  if (pos != 0)
     {
     char *end = strrchr( pos, '<' );
     if ( end )
        *end = '\0';
     printf("%s\n", pos + 1);
     }
```

The result is fairly brittle, though.  But depending on the input and desired use, maybe it is okay.

Comment: @Mark Wilkins Hi, just tried and it doesnt seem to work for multiple lines, only if there is only one line in the text file :(

Comment: @Den:  I only tried it with the example line from the file and it worked.  Does your file perhaps contain Unicode characters?  If so, you would need to use fgetws and other appropriate functions.

Comment: No it doesn't, odd because even with very similar filepaths it still only outputs one of them :S

Comment: @Mark Wilkins e.g. `report2011510222820.html: <td width="60%" bgcolor="#f4f4f4" class="tablebody" valign="top">C:\Users\Limited\Desktop\dmon_2.exe</td>
report2011510222820.html: <td width="60%" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="tablebody" valign="top">C:\dmon_2.exe</td>`

Comment: It only outputs one of the lines e.g. C:\Users\Limited\Desktop\dmon_2.exe and not the other (both are on different lines)

Comment: The original fputs call would not put in a line feed between the lines.  I changed it to a printf with a line feed included.  It printed both lines using the new sample data (it did before, but they were both on a single line).